# A normalized embedding $\mathbb C \rightarrow \mathfrak a_M^{\ast}$ via $\tilde{\alpha}$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, langlands-conjectures, reductive-groups, p-adic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected, reductive group over a field $k$.  Let $S$ be a maximal $k$-split torus of $G$ with Weyl group $W$, $\Delta$ a set of simple roots of $S$ in $G$, and $P = MN$ a maximal parabolic subgroup of $G$ with unipotent radical $N$ and Levi subgroup $M \supseteq S$.  Let $\alpha \in \Delta$ correspond to $P$.

If $(-,-)$ is any $W$-invariant symmetric, nondegenerate bilinear form on $\mathfrak a_S^{\ast} = X(S) \otimes \mathbb R$, set $\langle v, w \rangle = 2\frac{(v,w)}{(w,w)}$.  This is independent of the choice of $(-,-)$.

Let $\rho \in \mathfrak a_S^{\ast}$ be half the sum of the roots of $S$ in $N$, counting multiplicity, and define $$\tilde{\alpha} = \langle \rho,\alpha\rangle^{-1}\rho$$

Let $A_M$ be the split component of $M$, restrict $\tilde{\alpha}$ to an element of $X(A_M) \otimes \mathbb R$, and identify this restriction as an element of $\mathfrak a_M^{\ast} = X(M)_k \otimes \mathbb R$ via the isomorphism $\mathfrak a_M^{\ast} \cong X(A_M) \otimes \mathbb R$ induced by restriction $X(M)_k \rightarrow X(A_M)$.  Also call this element $\tilde{\alpha}$.

I have seen many papers in $p$-adic representation theory embed $\mathbb C$ into $\mathfrak a_M^{\ast} \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C$ by $s \mapsto s \tilde{\alpha}$.  When $k$ is $p$-adic, one may consider induced representations of the form

$$\operatorname{Ind}_{MN}^G \pi \otimes q_k^{\langle s \tilde{\alpha},H_M(-)\rangle}$$

and consider various operations on this which vary holomorphically with $s$.

1 .  What is the significance of embedding $\mathbb C$ into $\mathfrak a_M^{\ast}$ in this normalized way?  Why not just restrict $\rho$  to $X(A_M) \otimes \mathbb R \cong \mathfrak a_M^{\ast}$ and use $s \rho$ instead of $s \tilde{\alpha}$?

2 .  What, if anything, is significant about the character $\tilde{\alpha}$ from a representation-theoretic perspective?

3 .  When was $\tilde{\alpha}$ first defined?

Comment: Your statement that $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is independent of $(\cdot, \cdot)$ only works when the root system is irreducible, i.e., when the derived group of $G$ is (absolutely) simple.

Comment: I believe it is true in general.  On each irreducible component $Z \subset \Phi$ of the root system, the inner product $(-,-)$ is unique up to scalar multiple, so $\langle - , - \rangle$ is well defined on $Z \times Z$.  Outside of that case, $\langle - , - \rangle$ is identically zero.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry; you are right.